# How can I increase the size limit of a POST request?

Tags: java, android, post, http-headers

I'm developing an Android application and I'm sending a complex json data (with base64 encoded images) using [kevinsawicki/http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) library.

I'm doing something like this:

```
HttpRequest request =  HttpRequest.post(url)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .send(data);
```

`request.created()` returns `false` and `request.code()` is returning the http code **413**.

This code is...

> 413 Request Entity Too Large. The server will not accept the request, because the request entity is too large

So, I need to **increase the size limit** in order to send this huge amounts of data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: THis is set on the server.  You'll need to play with your webserver's settings, which is off topic for SO.  Try superuser (for once its actually the right place!)

Answer (score -1):

If your backend server is tomcat and jboss, their default max post size is 2M.

Please refer the following links:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html

```
maxPostSize 
The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).
```